# Correct way to obtain confidence interval with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, confidence-interval

I have a 1-dimensional array of data:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,6,7,8])
```

for which I want to obtain the 68% confidence interval (ie: the [1 sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)).

The first comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034101/1391441) states that this can be achieved using `scipy.stats.norm.interval` from the [scipy.stats.norm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm) function, via:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
mean, sigma = np.mean(a), np.std(a)

conf_int = stats.norm.interval(0.68, loc=mean, 
    scale=sigma)
```

But a comment in [this post](http://adventuresinpython.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/confidence-intervals-in-python.html) states that the *actual* correct way of obtaining the confidence interval is:

```
conf_int = stats.norm.interval(0.68, loc=mean, 
    scale=sigma / np.sqrt(len(a)))
```

that is, sigma is divided by the square-root of the sample size: `np.sqrt(len(a))`.

The question is: which version is the correct one?

Comment: you can use bootstrap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66008548/10375049

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The 68% confidence interval for **a single draw** from a normal distribution with
  mean mu and std deviation sigma is

```
stats.norm.interval(0.68, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
```

The 68% confidence interval for **the mean of N draws** from a normal distribution
  with mean mu and std deviation sigma is

```
stats.norm.interval(0.68, loc=mu, scale=sigma/sqrt(N))
```

Intuitively, these formulas make sense, since if you hold up a jar of jelly beans and ask a large number of people to guess the number of jelly beans, each individual may be off by a lot -- the same std deviation `sigma` -- but the average of the guesses will do a remarkably fine job of estimating the actual number and this is reflected by the standard deviation of the mean shrinking by a factor of `1/sqrt(N)`.

---

If a single draw has variance `sigma**2`, then by the [Bienaymé formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29), the sum of `N` *uncorrelated* draws has variance `N*sigma**2`.

The mean is equal to the sum divided by N. When you multiply a random variable (like the sum) by a constant, the variance is multiplied by the constant squared. That is

```
Var(cX) = c**2 * Var(X)
```

So the variance of the mean equals

```
(variance of the sum)/N**2 = N * sigma**2 / N**2 = sigma**2 / N
```

and so the standard deviation of the mean (which is the square root of the variance) equals

```
sigma/sqrt(N).
```

This is the origin of the `sqrt(N)` in the denominator.

---

Here is some example code, based on Tom's code, which demonstrates the claims made above:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

N = 10000
a = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
mean, sigma = a.mean(), a.std(ddof=1)
conf_int_a = stats.norm.interval(0.68, loc=mean, scale=sigma)

print('{:0.2%} of the single draws are in conf_int_a'
      .format(((a >= conf_int_a[0]) & (a < conf_int_a[1])).sum() / float(N)))

M = 1000
b = np.random.normal(0, 1, (N, M)).mean(axis=1)
conf_int_b = stats.norm.interval(0.68, loc=0, scale=1 / np.sqrt(M))
print('{:0.2%} of the means are in conf_int_b'
      .format(((b >= conf_int_b[0]) & (b < conf_int_b[1])).sum() / float(N)))
```

prints

```
68.03% of the single draws are in conf_int_a
67.78% of the means are in conf_int_b
```

Beware that if you define `conf_int_b` with the estimates for `mean` and `sigma`
based on the sample `a`, the mean may not fall in `conf_int_b` with the desired
frequency.

---

If you take a *sample* from a distribution and compute the
sample mean and std deviation,

```
mean, sigma = a.mean(), a.std()
```

be careful to note that there is no guarantee that these will 
equal the *population* mean and standard deviation and that we are *assuming*
the population is normally distributed -- those are not automatic givens!

If you take a sample and want to *estimate* the population mean and standard
deviation, you should use

```
mean, sigma = a.mean(), a.std(ddof=1)
```

since this value for sigma is the [unbiased estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) for the population standard deviation.

Comment: Great answer @unutbu, very thorough. Just to be sure I've covered my bases, how do you explain the example given in the other answer by Tom?

Comment: I think Tom's and my answers are in agreement. I've added some code based on his showing that single draws and means do fall in the confidence intervals with the expected frequency.

Comment: scipy.stats has the `sem` function `stats.sem(a) == a.std(ddof=1) / np.sqrt(len(a))` except for floating point errors

Comment: R and GraphPad use a sample size-dependent adjustment when calculating confidence intervals, which makes a notable difference for small sample sizes.  See my answer for details.

Comment: Should one also use `scale=sigma/sqrt(N)` if a single sample has been bootstrapped N times?

Answer (score 14):

I just checked how R and GraphPad calculate confidence intervals, and they increase the interval in case of small sample size (n).  E.g., more than 6-fold for n=2 compared to a large n.  This code (based on shasan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034143/1628638)) matches their confidence intervals:

```
import numpy as np, scipy.stats as st

# returns confidence interval of mean
def confIntMean(a, conf=0.95):
  mean, sem, m = np.mean(a), st.sem(a), st.t.ppf((1+conf)/2., len(a)-1)
  return mean - m*sem, mean + m*sem
```

For R, I checked against t.test(a).  GraphPad's [confidence interval of a mean](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?confidence_intervals.htm) page has "user level" info on the sample size dependency.

Here the output for Gabriel's example:

```
In [2]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,6,7,8])

In [3]: confIntMean(a, 0.68)
Out[3]: (3.9974214366806184, 4.877578563319382)

In [4]: st.norm.interval(0.68, loc=np.mean(a), scale=st.sem(a))
Out[4]: (4.0120010966037407, 4.8629989033962593)
```

Note that the difference between the `confIntMean()` and `st.norm.interval()` intervals is relatively small here; len(a) == 16 is not too small.

Answer (score 7):

I tested out your methods using an array with a known confidence interval. numpy.random.normal(mu,std,size) returns an array centered on mu with a standard deviation of std (in [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html), this is defined as `Standard deviation (spread or “width”) of the distribution.`).

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
a = random.normal(0,1,10000)
mean, sigma = np.mean(a), np.std(a)
conf_int_a = stats.norm.interval(0.68, loc=mean, scale=sigma)
conf_int_b = stats.norm.interval(0.68, loc=mean, scale=sigma / np.sqrt(len(a)))


conf_int_a
(-1.0011149125527312, 1.0059797764202412)
conf_int_b
(-0.0076030415111100983, 0.012467905378619625)
```

As the sigma value should be -1 to 1, the `/ np.sqrt(len(a))` method appears to be incorrect.

## Edit

Since I don't have the reputation to comment above I'll clarify how this answer ties into unutbu's thorough answer. If you populate a random array with a normal distribution, 68% of the total will fall within 1-σ of the mean. In the case above, if you check that you see

```
b = a[np.where((a>-1)&(a <1))]
len(a)
> 6781
```

or 68% of the population falls within 1σ. Well, about 68%. As you use a larger and larger array, you will approach 68% (In a trial of 10, 9 were between -1 and 1). That's because the 1-σ is the inherent distribution of the data, and the more data you have the better you can resolve it.

Basically, my interpretation of your question was **If I have a sample of data I want to use to describe the distribution they were drawn from, what is the method to find the standard deviation of that data?** whereas unutbu's interpretation appears to be more **What is the interval to which I can place the mean with 68% confidence?**. Which would mean, for jelly beans, I answered *How are they guessing* and unutbu answered *What do their guesses tell us about the jelly beans.*