# How to calculate one-sided tolerance interval with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, confidence-interval, reliability

I would like to calculate a one sided tolerance bound based on the normal distribution given a data set with known N (sample size), standard deviation, and mean.

If the interval were two sided I would do the following:

`conf_int = stats.norm.interval(alpha, loc=mean, scale=sigma)`

In my situation, I am bootstrapping samples, but if I weren't I would refer to this post on stackoverflow: [Correct way to obtain confidence interval with scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242593/correct-way-to-obtain-confidence-interval-with-scipy) and use the following: `conf_int = stats.norm.interval(0.68, loc=mean, scale=sigma / np.sqrt(len(a)))`

How would you do the same thing, but to calculate this as a one sided bound (95% of values are above or below x<--bound)?

Comment: None of the other scipy stats functions are useful? The docs should have a ling to the source for those functions - maybe you can repurpose one of them with minor changes.

Comment: See accepted answer - as far as I know none of the other functions would fit this problem but I would love to know about it if that changes or if I overlooked a function that would work for this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you are interested in computing one-side tolerance bound using the normal distribution (based on the fact you mention the `scipy.stats.norm.interval` function as the two-sided equivalent of your need).

Then the good news is that, based on the [tolerance interval Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_interval#Calculation):

> One-sided normal tolerance intervals have an exact solution in terms of the sample mean and sample variance based on the noncentral t-distribution.

(FYI: Unfortunately, this is not the case for the two-sided setting)

This assertion is based on [this paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v036i05). Besides paragraph 4.8 (page 23) provides the formulas.

The bad news is that I do not think there is a ready-to-use `scipy` function that you can safely tweak and use for your purpose.

But you can easily calculate it yourself. You can find on Github repositories that contain such a calculator from which you can find inspiration, for example [that one](https://github.com/cjekel/tolerance_interval_py) from which I built the following illustrative example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, nct

# sample size
n=1000

# Percentile for the TI to estimate
p=0.9
# confidence level
g = 0.95

# a demo sample
x = np.array([np.random.normal(100) for k in range(n)])

# mean estimate based on the sample
mu_est = x.mean()

# standard deviation estimated based on the sample
sigma_est = x.std(ddof=1)

# (100*p)th percentile of the standard normal distribution
zp = norm.ppf(p)

# gth quantile of a non-central t distribution
# with n-1 degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter np.sqrt(n)*zp
t = nct.ppf(g, df=n-1., nc=np.sqrt(n)*zp)

# k factor from Young et al paper
k = t / np.sqrt(n)

# One-sided tolerance upper bound
conf_upper_bound = mu_est + (k*sigma_est)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  You are correct, I was looking for a one-sided tolerance bound using the normal distribution - post edited.  I somehow didn't realize that two sided vs lower/upper bound differed so greatly mathematically and this is a very helpful example!!  Thank you for the detail on this response

Comment: @Greta, you can consider accepting the answer if it addressed you question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. comments might get deleted, and it would help if someone faces a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line solution with the openturns library, assuming your data is a numpy array named `sample`.

```
import openturns as ot
ot.NormalFactory().build(sample.reshape(-1, 1)).computeQuantile(0.95)
```

Let us unpack this. `NormalFactory` is a class designed to fit the parameters of a Normal distribution (*mu* and *sigma*) on a given sample: `NormalFactory()` creates an instance of this class.

The method `build` does the actual fitting and returns an object of the class `Normal` which represents the normal distribution with parameters *mu* and *sigma* estimated from the sample.

The `sample` reshape is there to make sure that OpenTURNS understands that the input `sample` is a collection of one-dimension points, not a single multi-dimensional point.

The class `Normal` then provides the method `computeQuantile` to compute any quantile of the distribution (the 95-th percentile in this example).

This solution does not compute the exact tolerance bound because it uses a quantile from a Normal distribution instead of a Student t-distribution. Effectively, that means that it ignores the estimation error on *mu* and *sigma*. In practice, this is only an issue for really small sample sizes.

To illustrate this, here is a comparison between the PDF of the standard normal N(0,1) distribution and the PDF of the Student t-distribution with 19 degrees of freedom (this means a sample size of 20). They can barely be distinguished.

```
deg_freedom = 19
graph = ot.Normal().drawPDF()
student = ot.Student(deg_freedom).drawPDF().getDrawable(0)
student.setColor('blue')
graph.add(student)
graph.setLegends(['Normal(0,1)', 't-dist k={}'.format(deg_freedom)])
graph
```

[image: Compare Normal and Student t distributions]

Comment: Hello and thank you for commenting.  Can you clarify and let me know if this is a onesided output?

Comment: Yes, 95% of all values are below the given bound.