# Estimate confidence intervals for parameters of distribution in python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

Is there a built in function that will provide the confidence intervals for parameter estimates in a python package or is this something I will need to implement by hand?  I am looking for something similar to matlabs gevfit http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gevfit.html.

Comment: you can use bootstrap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66008548/10375049

Answer (score 2):

The bootstrap can be used to estimate confidence intervals of any function (`np.mean`, `st.genextreme.fit`, etc.) of a sample, and there is a Python library: [`scikits.bootstrap`](https://scikits.appspot.com/bootstrap).

Here for the data from the question author's related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35732847/1628638):

```
import numpy as np, scipy.stats as st, scikits.bootstrap as boot
data = np.array([ 22.20379411,  22.99151292,  24.27032696,  24.82180626,
  25.23163221,  25.39987272,  25.54514567,  28.56710007,
  29.7575898 ,  30.15641696,  30.79168255,  30.88147532,
  31.0236419 ,  31.17380647,  31.61932755,  32.23452568,
  32.76262978,  33.39430032,  33.81080069,  33.90625861,
  33.99142006,  35.45748368,  37.0342621 ,  37.14768791,
  38.14350221,  42.72699534,  44.16449992,  48.77736737,
  49.80441736,  50.57488779])

st.genextreme.fit(data)   # just to check the parameters
boot.ci(data, st.genextreme.fit)
```

The results are

```
(-0.014387281261850815, 29.762126238637851, 5.8983127779873605)
array([[ -0.40002507,  26.93511496,   4.6677834 ],
       [  0.19743722,  32.41834882,   9.05026202]])
```

The bootstrap takes about three minutes on my machine; by default, `boot.ci` uses 10,000 bootstrap iterations (`n_samples`), see [code](https://github.com/cgevans/scikits-bootstrap/blob/0.3.2/scikits/bootstrap/bootstrap.py#L13) or `help(boot.ci)`, and `st.genextreme.fit` is not superfast.

The confidence intervals from `boot.ci` do not match the ones from MATLAB's [`gevfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gevfit.html) exactly.  E.g., MATLAB gives a symmetric one [-0.3032, 0.3320] for the first parameter (0.0144).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - however what if I want to specify a parameter for the distribution fitting, e.g. a location parameter, I can't get it to work, e.g. `boot.ci(data, genextreme.fit(data, loc=0))`  - as it says a tuple object not callable.

Comment: @dreab, something like `boot.ci(data, lambda x: st.genextreme.fit(x, loc=29.7))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `scipy` and `numpy` in case you haven't already. If you have some familiarity with MATLAB, then the switch should be relatively easy. I've taken this quick snippet from [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034143/3672986):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats

def mean_confidence_interval(data, confidence=0.95):
    a = 1.0*np.array(data)
    n = len(a)
    m, se = np.mean(a), scipy.stats.sem(a)
    h = se * sp.stats.t.ppf((1+confidence)/2., n-1)
    return m, m-h, m+h
```

You should be able to customize the returns to your liking. Like the MATLAB `gevfit` function, it defaults to using 95% confidence bounds.

Comment: Please use `ppf` instead of `_ppf`

Comment: @captain_M, this does not provide a "range that contains the percent of the population"; it provides the confidence interval of the `mean` parameter.