# How to calculate confidence interval in Intel Galileo Gen 2

Tags: python, scipy, intel, intel-galileo

I'm using scipy's module stats to calculate the confidence interval from a population normal distributed like someone has already done here ([Compute a confidence interval from sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033511/compute-a-confidence-interval-from-sample-data)). But I've failed all my attempts to get scipy installed on intel galileo gen 2. Is there any way to do it without scipy? Thank you.

Comment: You can calculate the confidence interval if you have the variance.  If you do (the math is fairly easy) then this is now a math question, so I suggest that you ask this question in math.stackexchange.com  The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) is also very useful

Comment: But I dont have the variance of the population, so I have to calculate the T distribution. I only know how to do that in python using scipy.

Comment: Without knowing more about your problem, I would still assume that the calculations for the confidence interval would be some kind of math equation.  If you would like to do the math, you would need to share more details about your problem