# How can I build a confidence interval calculator in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I need some help with calculating the confidence interval for a range of sample sizes and according population sizes. So I have a data frame with 3 columns; 1 column has the country name in it, one column the sample size of a survey that was done in that country, and one column has the population size. I want to iterate through those sample sizes and population sizes and calculate the confidence interval for each sample. Only thing is, I have no idea where to start.

Basically, I want to build something like the 'find confidence interval' calculator (the 2nd one) on this page: http://www.surveysystem.com/sscalc.htm, only thing is I want to pass a list of sample sizes and population sizes. I hope you guys can help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, for example, I've been looking at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033511/compute-a-confidence-interval-from-sample-data

However, in that post the confidence interval is calculate without using the population size. I'm not sure how that even works.

Comment: So are you stuck on how to build a confidence interval calculator, or how to apply it to your data?

Comment: Building the calculator.

Comment: So best place to start is to read about the key concepts here: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat100/node/56 then add some code once you've built something so it can be commented on specifically.