# Random Choice with Pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a tensor of pictures, and would like to randomly select from it. I'm looking for the equivalent of `np.random.choice()`.

```
import torch

pictures = torch.randint(0, 256, (1000, 28, 28, 3))
```

Let's say I want 10 of these pictures.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`torch` has no equivalent implementation of `np.random.choice()`, see the discussion [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16897). The alternative is indexing with a shuffled index or random integers.

### To do it *with* replacement:

1. Generate *n* random indices
2. Index your original tensor with these indices

```
pictures[torch.randint(len(pictures), (10,))]
```

### To do it *without* replacement:

1. Shuffle the index
2. Take the *n* first elements

```
indices = torch.randperm(len(pictures))[:10]

pictures[indices]
```

Read more about [`torch.randint`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.randint) and [`torch.randperm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.randperm). Second code snippet is inspired by this [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-equivalent-of-numpy-random-choice/16146/2) in PyTorch Forums.

Answer (score 12):

[`torch.multinomial`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.multinomial.html#torch.multinomial) provides equivalent behaviour to numpy's [`random.choice`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-equivalent-of-numpy-random-choice/16146/13) (including sampling with/without replacement):

```py
# Uniform weights for random draw
unif = torch.ones(pictures.shape[0])

idx = unif.multinomial(10, replacement=True)
samples = pictures[idx]
```

```py
samples.shape
>>> torch.Size([10, 28, 28, 3])
```

Comment: The `.multinomial()` method has a limitation in that it only works on tensors of up to `2**24` (=16777216) elements: `RuntimeError: number of categories cannot exceed 2^24`.  `torch.randperm()` doesn't face this limitation, but it does take a very long time for larger numbers e.g. `2**30`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60564584/3126298) below. Torch version 2.0.1 and NumPy 1.24.3.

Answer (score 7):

For this size of tensor:

```py
N, D = 386363948, 2
k = 190973
values = torch.randn(N, D)
```

The following code works fairly fast. It takes around 0.2s:

```py
indices = torch.tensor(random.sample(range(N), k))
indices = torch.tensor(indices)
sampled_values = values[indices]
```

Using `torch.randperm`, however, would take more than 20s:

```py
sampled_values = values[torch.randperm(N)[:k]]
```

Comment: If `k` becomes large i.e. you need to sample many numbers from the sequence, it becomes faster to use numpy: `np.random.default_rng().choice(2**40, 2**7, replace=False)`.  On my machine, for `k > 2**6`, numpy is faster. For `k <= 2**6`, `random.sample(N, k)` is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
input_tensor = torch.randn(5, 8)
print(input_tensor)
indices = torch.LongTensor(np.random.choice(5,2, replace=False)) 
output_tensor = torch.index_select(input_tensor, 0, indices)
print(output_tensor)
```

Answer (score -1):

As the other answer mentioned, torch does not have `choice`. You can use `randint` or permutation instead:

```
import torch

n = 4
replace = True # Can change
choices = torch.rand(4, 3)
choices_flat = choices.view(-1)

if replace:
    index = torch.randint(choices_flat.numel(), (n,))
else:
    index = torch.randperm(choices_flat.numel())[:n]

select = choices_flat[index]
```