# How to select 5% of total values from a tensor randomly?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

`a = torch.rand(2,5,10)`
I want to select at most 5% of values from tensor `a` randomly and then multiply those values with `-1`? How to do that? kindly, give a generic solution as the shape of the tensor is not fixed

Comment: Do you want to select <=5% of values? Or do you want to select exactly 5% of values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random Choice with Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461811/random-choice-with-pytorch)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
out = (torch.rand_like(a) - 0.05).sign().type_as(a) * a
```