# Pytorch random choose an index with condition

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor that stores whether or not an index in available

```py
available = torch.Tensor([1,1,0,0,1,0])
```

and I want to return an index of either 0, 1, or 4 given that `available[0]`,`available[1]`,`available[4]` all equal to 1 with the same possibility.

can somebody help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torch makes this easy. You can use [multinomial](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.multinomial.html#torch.multinomial) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66635551/11659881):

```
num_samples = 1
available.multinomial(num_samples, replacement=False)
```

Here, `num_samples` indicates how many samples you'd like to draw.

Because you have `1`s and `0`s already, your `available` tensor naturally gives the correct weights for the multinomial function.

If you are going to draw more than 3 samples, this will error unless you change `replacement` to `True`.