# Is there any method in Pytorch as the "numpy.random.choice" function in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Is there any method in Pytorch as the same as the "numpy.random.choice" function in NumPy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random Choice with Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461811/random-choice-with-pytorch)

Answer (score 0):

You can try torch.randint function. for sample data with a range 0 to n with size m for example.

```
sample = torch.randint(low=0, high=n, size(m,))
```

Comment: torch.randint() is uniform sampling.

Comment: We cannot customize the probability matrix like  "numpy.random.choice" function

Comment: The method I came up with is to first convert it to a numpy array, and then convert it to a tensor.

Comment: can you try torch.multinomial. it can accept probabilities. 
sample = torch.multinomial([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], m, replacement=True)