# Calculate accuracy of a tensor compared to a target tensor

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have my output tensor like this:

```
tensor([[0.1834, 0.8166],
        [0.3031, 0.6969],
        [0.3104, 0.6896],
        [0.3065, 0.6935],
        [0.3060, 0.6940],
        [0.2963, 0.7037],
        [0.2340, 0.7660],
        [0.2302, 0.7698],
        [0.2581, 0.7419],
        [0.2081, 0.7919]], grad_fn=<PowBackward0>)
```

I would like to first convert my output tensor to something like this:

```
tensor([1., 1., 1......])
```

where the value indicate the index of the larger value(for example, 0.8166 > 0.1834 so the first element is 1).

Any suggestions would by appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's literally just `your_tensor.argmax(dim=1)`.

`your_tensor.argmax(dim=1).float()` if you truly need it to be float.

After that, the accuracy can be calculated as `sum(my_tensor == target_tensor) / len(target_tensor)`, for example. (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503851/calculate-the-accuracy-every-epoch-in-pytorch)).

Answer (score 0):

To get the index with the largest value you should use [`torch.argmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.argmax.html).

Related PyTorch commands that can be used here are also:

- [`torch.max`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.max.html): this command (when used with `dim` argument) returns the max value and the index of that value along the specified dimension.
- [`torch.topk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.topk.html): returns the top `k` elements along a dimension. When `k=1` works like `torch.max`.